# Read column/list containing urls by skipping blank cells using python

Tags: python, pandas, automation, python-requests

1. I have a column all_sheet_url in google sheet which has some url links in it.
   I need to read them one by one and fetch data from them.
   As there are some blanks/NA also in the column which I want to skip.

- List item

I have tried with following code, but its not working to read only url and skip blanks if any in the column.

```
sheet_url = df['Links']
    for line in sheet_url:
        #if line in sheet_url:
        try:
            url = line
            req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
            r.raise_for_status()
            # checking if it is an html page
            content_type = req.headers.get('content-type')
            if 'html' in content_type or 'application/xhtml+xml' in content_type:
                # reading the contents
                html = req.content
                # req.close()
                output = html
                print(output)
                continue
            else:
                 print("\t{} is not an HTML file".format(url))
                 #req.close()
        except Exception:
            return
```

Kindly please suggest a method/corrections for the same, Thanks.

2. I need to read range of data from url and write in main google sheet.
   I am able to read and write for single url at once.But, I want it to be dynamic so that it should read and write range of data from urls continously automatically by taking index of that url placed in the column.
   This is the code I have tried with,

```
wks = gc.open_by_url(url)
wks1 = gc.open_by_url(url1)
  # Defining Range of cells to read
range1 = wks1.range('A5:A9')
range2 = wks1.range('A5:B9')
range3 = wks1.range('G11:L19')
range4 = wks1.range('B12:C13')

# Defining Range of cells to write
range1n = wks.range('CO43:CS43')
range2n = wks.range('CT43:DR43')
range3n = wks.range('DS43:FK43')
range4n = wks.range('FL43:FM43')
range_names = [['range1', 'range2', 'range3', 'range4']]

for range1_cell, range1n_cell in zip(range1, range1n):
    range1n_cell.value = range1_cell.value
    wks.update_cells(range1n)
```

Answer (score 1):

pandas has a `dropna` method to do exactly what you need.

Documentation: [`pandas.Series.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html)

In your cas that could just be the same processing code with the first line being:

```py
all_sheet_url = df['Workbook Link'].dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,I dont want to drop cells directly, I just need to skip blanks from column containing urls !?

Comment: `dropna` does not actually change the initial `df` object unless you use the optional argument `inplace=True`. What my line of code actually does:
1- Isolate the `'Workbook Link'` column
2- Remove the N/A-blank items in it
3- Assign it to a whole new object (`all_sheet_url`)